# How do you keep a Form open after 'Yes' is clicked on a Message Box?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a login for a project which I'm making, but what's annoying, is that whenever I click Yes, on my message box, the whole project just closes, which I don't want to happen.

Here's the code:

```
MsgBox("You have been successfully logged into our database!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success!")
        Else
            MsgBox("Sorry, it looks like those values are incorrect, would you like to try again?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Whoops!")
            If vbNo Then
                Application.Exit()
            Else
                If vbYes Then
                    Me.Show()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see in the vbYes line of code, I'm trying to make it so the message box closes only, but not the actual project so people can try again.

Comment: Store the result of MsgBox() and then test the result. `dim result=MsgBox(...)`... `if result = vbNo then`. Right now you're testing against a constant which is always true

Comment: You are using the leftovers from `vb6`, ***MsgBox***... Use `MessageBox` along with `ShowDialog`...

Comment: Zualux, would you consider accepting the answer below? To do so, click on the tick icon to the left of it, so that it turns green. That's how we mark a question as done here, and it thanks the helpful answerer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
MsgBox("Sorry, it looks like those values are incorrect, would you like to try again?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Whoops!")
If vbNo Then
    Application.Exit()
Else
    If vbYes Then
        Me.Show()
    End If
End If
```

should be this:

```
If MsgBox("Sorry, it looks like those values are incorrect, would you like to try again?",
          MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo,
          "Whoops!") = vbNo Then
    Application.Exit()
Else
    Me.Show()
End If
```

I can't recommend strongly enough that you turn `Option Strict On` in this project and in the IDE so it's `On` for every other project you create in future.  The code you have wouldn't even compile with `Option Strict On` and that is a sign that you're trying to do something that you shouldn't.  `vbNo` and `vbYes` are not `Boolean` values and so should not be the subject of an `If` statement.